# Word/phrase for looking up and down repeatedly?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Example:

> He took out the picture of the building and compared it with the live
>   version, [...].

I'm not sure how to search for that on Google or Thesaurus.

Comment: his eyes darting between them repeatedly.

Comment: This thread gets my vote for funniest of the day!  //  But seriously, @janoChen, try **scanning**, for example, *scanning between them, looking for any discernable difference*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write it out. It'll make for a better story anyhow.

> ...He looked at the building, then back at the painting, then up at the building again, something wasn't right. Lola had been trying to tell him, but he had ignored her, hadn't wanted to hear it. He was still staring. Looking back and forth. What was it that was so off about it? What was it that wa... He stood, gaping, as struck by lightning. There was a.. How could he not have seen it, seriously, how? How could that not be the first thing anyone saw. It was right there bright as day...